# Add custom name in Routing Razor Area

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I want to add a custom name to have a client specific routing as a base for an area.
But not sure how to go about setting this up.

So let's say i have the area "Webportal", which gives the url:  domain.com/Webportal/Index for the main page.
But i want to have it like:  domain.com/Webportal/friendlyname/Index or for another portal: domain.com/Webportal/anothername/Index, where "friendlyname" and "anothername" are dynamic names that are tied to a database value.. so these should not be fixed routes

To further show what i'm trying to achieve is that I have this link:

```
<a asp-page="/Index" asp-area="Webportal" asp-route-name="@item.StoreOpenFriendlyName"></a>
```

Let's say StoreOpenFriendlyName = "Testshop"

And in effect i want to keep the customer on the following URI for all pages in that area:

```
/Webportal/TestShop/Index/
/Webportal/TestShop/Index/Optionalparameter
/Webportal/TestShop/Checkout/
/Webportal/TestShop/Cart/Optionalparameter
```

etc.

This is in a razor pages ASP netcore setup, 5.0.

Thanks for the help!

Edit:

Ok, i figured it out, all you gotta do is add this to startup.cs, for example:

```
    services.AddRazorPages()
        .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Webportal", "/Checkout", "Webportal/{name?}/Checkout");
        });
```

Comment: you can configure the area route and format (the pattern) it whatever way you want. If that's not dynamic enough, please update your question (about the static way and requirement for a more dynamic way).

Comment: Edited the question. Although it's probably a simple thing, it's difficult to explain! haha. Thanks for answering King King

Comment: Actually I was asking for your area route configuration, e.g: `MapAreaRoute(....)` - you should achieve what you want by configuring it just by that standard way. If that's not enough, plz explain why.

Comment: Well that's the thing, i do not have any route set, since razor handles that for you